# What is a non-winter themed snow globe called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Most people are familiar with snowglobes: fist-sized glass spheres that have 3D sculptures inside, and upon shaking the globe, the white flakes inside simulate snowfall.

However, I imagine that there must exist non-winter themed "snowglobes" (perhaps their theme is based on a city, or on mountains, etc.). I would like to purchase one of these, but I don't know what it's called. So my question is, what is the more general name for "snowglobes" that includes globes with any other theme?

Comment: I've never heard them called anything other than "snow globe". I'm not sure what you mean about other themes given that I've never seen one without the "snow", even when showing a scene from somewhere that doesn't typically get snow in real life.

Comment: I am looking for stuff like this (please see link below). Whether it does or doesn't have flakes is not so important to me.It's just that whenever I type in "snowglobe" somewhere, I always find winter/Christmas themed globes; I would like to know what I should type in so that I can find globes with other themes. https://www.amazon.com/Cat-Books-Snow-Globes-CoolSnowGlobes/dp/B01EKJFDYE?ref_=ast_bbp_dp&th=1&psc=1

Comment: But even your Cat & Book example is explicitly called a "snow globe". I just typed "snow globe" into Amazon's search and found a whole lot of items that have nothing to do with winter or Christmas. Same with a Google search. (Of course there are some winter and Christmas ones in the search results, but plenty of other options too.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Right; but the vast majority of results involve winter, so I was wondering if I am perhaps missing out on the market of non-winter ones by not knowing the right term.

Comment: Another term is _water globe_. For example, [Hallmark](https://www.hallmark.com/gifts/home-decor/snow-globes/) uses the title "Snow Globes & Water Globes". However, _snow globe_ can still be used for all versions including non-winter themed ones. Google image search result for "water globe" seems to be less wintery but winter themed versions are the most popular ones.

Comment: To follow up on ermanen's comment, another relevant term is "[glitter globe](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22glitter+globe%22&lr=&as_qdr=all&sxsrf=ACYBGNQI-Bu3BX67dDwsLavuaTujgaEAQA:1581287403851&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit5vnPwsXnAhVDs54KHYmEAh4Qsxh6BAgMECw&biw=1086&bih=1033)" (for water-filled globes that use glitter rather than white flakes as the ersatz snow.

Comment: This one https://www.universitycoop.com/Austin-Texas-Flying-Bats-Snow-Globe?gclid=EAIaIQobChMItNLvjMbF5wIVdR-tBh1EVwZrEAQYASABEgKCUfD_BwE is still called a snow globe but this one is a “water globe” https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LXYEF5I/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_kXiqEbTXGX5KG